# FlashDevelop 5.1 StackFrame Panel Triggers Internal Debugger Exception

Tags: debugging, ide, flashdevelop

**What setting/feature am I not configuring properly to have my StackFrame Panel back to a working state?**

- OS: Windows 10 64bit
- IDE: FlashDevelop 5.1.1.1 for .NET 3.5 (32bit and 64bit behave the same)
- Lang: ActionScript 3.0 SDK: Flex 4.6 + AIR
- 21.0 (Tried Several versions of each)
- Player: Flash Player(SA) Debug ver 21.0
- Java: JDK/JRE 7u80
- Libs: AppWarp42.swc, AppWarpLibS2-1.0.8.swc, Assets.swc (Custom) and starling.swc(disabled)

**Expected Behaviour:**
Errors triggered during debugging pops up the StackFrame Panel with frame calls that can be clicked.

**Actual Behaviour:**
When starting the debugger(manually or autorun enabled) via FlashDevelop, everything is good until an error occurs. Instead of showing the stack trace, I get an Internal Debugger Error and anytime I attempt to set a previous StackFrame to the current frame, the same error retriggers:

[Internal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR88c.png)

```
    See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
flash.tools.debugger.NoResponseException: Timeout occurred while waiting for debugging response from Flash Player for 1000 milliseconds


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8689 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
FlashDevelop
    Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 5.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/FlashDevelop64.exe
----------------------------------------
PluginCore
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/PluginCore.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8670 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8690 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8681 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8679 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.8693 built by: QFE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
AirProperties
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/AirProperties.DLL
----------------------------------------
AS2Context
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/AS2Context.DLL
----------------------------------------
ASCompletion
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/ASCompletion.DLL
----------------------------------------
AS3Context
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/AS3Context.DLL
----------------------------------------
XMLCompletion
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/XMLCompletion.DLL
----------------------------------------
Aga
    Assembly Version: 1.7.0.1
    Win32 Version: 1.7.0.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Aga.DLL
----------------------------------------
ASClassWizard
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/ASClassWizard.DLL
----------------------------------------
BasicCompletion
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.18867
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.18867
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/BasicCompletion.DLL
----------------------------------------
BookmarkPanel
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/BookmarkPanel.DLL
----------------------------------------
BridgeSettings
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/BridgeSettings.DLL
----------------------------------------
CodeAnalyzer
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/CodeAnalyzer.DLL
----------------------------------------
CodeFormatter
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/CodeFormatter.DLL
----------------------------------------
Antlr3
    Assembly Version: 3.1.3.42154
    Win32 Version: 3.1.3.42154
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Antlr3.DLL
----------------------------------------
CodeRefactor
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/CodeRefactor.DLL
----------------------------------------
CssCompletion
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/CssCompletion.DLL
----------------------------------------
DataEncoder
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/DataEncoder.DLL
----------------------------------------
fdb.j4n
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 0.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/fdb.j4n.DLL
----------------------------------------
jni4net.n-0.8.8.0
    Assembly Version: 0.8.8.0
    Win32 Version: 0.8.8.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/jni4net.n-0.8.8.0.DLL
----------------------------------------
FileExplorer
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/FileExplorer.DLL
----------------------------------------
FlashConnect
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/FlashConnect.DLL
----------------------------------------
FlashDebugger
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/FlashDebugger.DLL
----------------------------------------
FlashLogViewer
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/FlashLogViewer.DLL
----------------------------------------
FlashViewer
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/FlashViewer.DLL
----------------------------------------
HaXeContext
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/HaXeContext.DLL
----------------------------------------
jni4net.n.w32.v20-0.8.8.0
    Assembly Version: 0.8.8.0
    Win32 Version: 0.8.8.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/jni4net.n.w32.v20-0.8.8.0.DLL
----------------------------------------
LayoutManager
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/LayoutManager.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Design
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8670 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Design/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Design.dll
----------------------------------------
LoomContext
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/LoomContext.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProjectManager
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/ProjectManager.DLL
----------------------------------------
MacroManager
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/MacroManager.DLL
----------------------------------------
OutputPanel
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/OutputPanel.DLL
----------------------------------------
PHPContext
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/PHPContext.DLL
----------------------------------------
SwfOp
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/SwfOp.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8670 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
ResultsPanel
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/ResultsPanel.DLL
----------------------------------------
SourceControl
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/SourceControl.DLL
----------------------------------------
StartPage
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/StartPage.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Web
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8670 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_64/System.Web/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
TaskListPanel
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/TaskListPanel.DLL
----------------------------------------
WakaTime
    Assembly Version: 1.1.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.1.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Jeramey/AppData/Local/FlashDevelop/Plugins/WakaTime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8670 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
4y8lvnbq
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8690 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
qipjfbig
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8690 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
8brvfzkj
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8690 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8670 (QFE.050727-8600)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll
----------------------------------------
net.sf.jni4net.jni.dynammic
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 0.8.8.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/FlashDevelop/Plugins/jni4net.n-0.8.8.0.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

I have tried the following corrective steps without any improvement:

- Reset FlashDevelop(FD) Settings
- Reinstalled FD
- Rolled back FD to previous versions
- Rolled back Flash Player to previous versions (12 was the farthest I went)
- Rolled back Java JDK and JRE versions 7u79, 7u80, 8u91 and 8u92
- Created new project (Different issues arise)
- Set all apps that run to Administrative Access
- Verified Network ports and port securities for apps
- Looped through the last 20 revisions of project from SVN
- Searched for the elusive "machine.config" file

I look forward to illuminating my blind spot, thanks all.